# Parent and child window connection with JS

Tags: javascript, html

So I am new to Javascript and right now I am trying to make it so a child window/tab created from a parent page can affect said parent page.

I made a parent page with a button that opens a child page and on that child page upon choosing an option input and pressing a button the value should also appear on the parent page, but they don't and I am not sure why.

Here is the Parent page

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Name:&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="txtName" readonly="readonly" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" value="Select Name" onclick="SelectName()" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var popup;
    function SelectName() {
        popup = window.open("popup.html", "width=300,height=100");
        popup.focus();
        return false
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the Child page

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select name="ddlNames" id="ddlNames">
    <option value="Name1">Name1</option>
    <option value="Name2">Name2</option>
    <option value="Name3">Name3</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="Select" onclick="SetName();" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetName() {
        if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
            var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("txtName");
            txtName.value = document.getElementById("ddlNames").value;
        }
        window.close();
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am confused as to why the selected values from Child page don't appear in the Parent page.

Comment: i dont understand why you would like to do something like this, say instead of a `modal` which can be easier to implement and manage, but a possible solution might be to store the selected values in the cookies if possible, then fetching the stored value from the cookies. but this creates the problem of fetching it upon closing the page.

Comment: It's an outdated way to do it, but anyway I copied your code as-is and it works as expected on my PC.

Comment: @MeBottleOScrumpy I tried this way cuz I am learning and don't know better, so is using cookies the best way to implement this kind of functionality?

Comment: @Akzhol i just had never seen an approach like this, thats why i was confused, as Benny said it might be one of old approaches, but one way to achieve a similar functionality might be a simple `modal`. something like this ---> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp . i dont know if it is the best way to implement it or not, but you can create a simple form or input filed inside the `modal` and when you are done with getting what you want, you simple close or hide it. A `multi-step form` might solve the problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is blocked by this error:

```
DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
```

You'll need to serve the files by setting up a simple server, and then opening `parent.html`.

You can solve this by:

- Installing node.js and npm
- Running `npm install -g http-server` in your terminal.
- Running `http-server` command in the folder where your html files are located

When you open the hosted files, the popup file should now be able to access and modify the parent file that called it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @AsthaBist That didn't work for me, where or how did you see that error message btw?

Comment: In the browser's console